# Getting ASIN from text using Python and re

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, python-re

I'm trying to get asins from my text. But I didn't achieve it yet. I tried using `re` but it didn't help me so much. It always gave me `None` result.

Here's my text:

```
/data.txt

FolkArt One Stroke Palette  
FolkArt One Stroke Palette
B0007TZY3W
AMZRSG1890951279
4.6 review rate122

Deleter | Manga Tool Kit SPDX   
Deleter | Manga Tool Kit SPDX
B000DZTROC
AMZRSG1890951289
4.6 review rate46
```

And I want to get this result:

```
['B0007TZY3W', 'B000DZTROC']
```

Here's what I tried:

```
# Get ASINS from data text file
with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = re.search(r'B(.*) AMZRSG', str(data))
    print(data)
```

The result is:

```
None
```

How can I achieve this result? I tried to get it with `re` but as I said it didn't work. Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Try using one of the regex websites like https://regex101.com/ to develop your regex; much faster feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the newline character into your regex:

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = file.read()
    asins = re.findall(r'B(.*)\nAMZRSG', str(data))

    for asin in asins:
        print(f'B{asin}')
```

Out:

```
B0007TZY3W
B000DZTROC
```